# Using Memcached with PHP on Amazaon EC2

Tags: php, caching, amazon-ec2, memcached

I have installed and started memcached service on my Amazon EC2 Instance.
When I visit my phpinfo page http://verygoodtrips.com/phpinfo.php it shows the entries for Memcached

Now when I am trying to use Memcache in my php using the following code

```
  $memcache = new Memcache;
  $key = md5('Unique'); // Unique Words
  $memcache->set($key, "Hello", MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 1200);
  print_r($memcache->get($key));
```

Here's the php page with above source code
http://verygoodtrips.com/memcache.php

I am getting Internal Server Error (500). I am new to using Memcached, so it would be nice if someone can point me in right direction

Comment: 500 error isn't indicative of much. Try taking a look at your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing at first but there's both Memcache and Memcached.

```
 $cache = new Memcached();
 $key = md5('Unique'); // Unique Words
 $cache->set($key, "Hello", 1200);
 print_r($cache->get($key));
```

And for ease: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php

Comment: This did solved the Internal Server Error, but now its var_dump($Memcached->getResultCode()) throws int(47) which means MEMCACHED_SERVER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED

Comment: Whoops I missed the add server line...

$cache->addServer('localhost', 11211);

If this doesn't work, make sure you can telnet to localhsot port 11211 to make sure memcached is running locally.